# How to convert an iterative algorithm to recursive solution

Tags: c, recursion, for-loop

I have this which solves a problem iteratively using a for loop. I want to convert the code to use a recursive algorithm using if-else statement that uses recursion. I've tried several times but I can't get it to work properly.

```
double A;
int B;
double previous=1; 
double answer;

double equation(double A,int B){
 for(int i=1; i<=B; i++){    
  answer= (A*previous)/(i+A*previous);    
  previous = answer;                  
 };
 return answer;                 
}
```

EDIT: Here's what I've done so far: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kyeq1v5u

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  If so please tag it as such.

Comment: Sorry for not tagging. Yes it is an assignment in class but I coded the for loop.

Comment: You should also show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I've added my attempt at converting it to recursion already.

Comment: Your attempt is completely missing one essential part of recursion; the recursive function call.

Answer (score 4):

Have a formula.  It is a recursive formula.  It defines your problem, recursively

```
equation(A, B) =
    IF(B = 1) 
        A/(1+A)  
    ELSE
        (A*equation(B-1)) / (B+A*equation(B-1))
```

Edited:  There is your complete algorithm in psudo-code.  all you have to do is translate to c.  Good Luck.

hint:  `previous` is equal to `equation(A, B-1)`

Comment: That formula is right. But how can I code that using if-else recursive sequence?

Comment: See the hint.  Think about this: how would you just have a function that just counts from 1 to B using recursion?

Comment: @imuser31250  If you need another push toward the answer, the formula I posted IS the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

When thinking about recursive approach, first come up with the condition that ends the recursion bearing in mind that typically recursion progresses in the opposite direction than iterative approach in this kind of functions.

In your case function signature would probably be the same, and each recursive call would have B one smaller than on previous round. Ending condition would be something that you can easily calculate, for example B=1.

Also, you don't need any global variables that you have declared in your code. Use local variables instead so they all can have different values in each recursive function call. It is also bad habit to use global variables when you can avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

pseudo code (There might be some small mistake but it should get you thinking in the right direction

```
Equation A , B = Equation_internal( A, B , 1, 1)


Equation_internal (A , B , i , prev ) = 
  case i <= B   : return  Equation_internal ( A , B , i+1 , (A* prev )/(i+A*prev) )
  otherwise return prev.
```

Comment: you seem to understand recursion about as well as the op does

Comment: @Sam You mean because that's just the most general solution on how to transform a iterative into a recursive solution?

Comment: While it is *technically* recursive, it doesn't really apply recursive principles.  The variables `i` and `prev` are superfluous.

Comment: @SamIam did i do something wrong o.0 .. this is the simplest answer i could think of

Comment: @BrianNickel post a better solution for us?

Comment: I did post an answer, which is psudo-code.  It's more of a functional language psudocode, but recursion is a functional principle

Comment: why are the parameters for the equation(A,B,1,1)? Shouldn't it be(A,B,0,1)?

Comment: @OsamaJaved, I would but SamIam and Jari already posted excellent explanations.  I suggest reading Jari's answer for a better understanding of how to construct a recursive function.  It's the same basic principle as mathematical induction: start at the bottom and then build up from there.

Answer (score -2):

here my little code

```
double equation(double A,int B);
double equation2(double A,int B, int curcount, double previous);


double A;
int B;
double previous=1; 
double answer;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{


   double toto= equation(5,3);

   double toto2= equation2(5,3,0,1);


    return 0;
}

double equation(double A,int B){
    for(int i=1; i<=B; i++){    
        previous= (A*previous)/(i+A*previous);    
    };
    return previous;                 
}

double equation2(double A,int B, int curcount, double previous){

    if (curcount == B) {
        return previous;
    }else{
        curcount++;
        previous= (A*previous)/(curcount+A*previous); 

        return equation2(A,B,curcount,previous);
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe that your equation2 will result in a Stack Overflow.  Also, don't post full code for homework

Comment: why stack overflow ? no, I tested and is conform with the pseudocode above. and i did not know it was a homework (and as a matter of fact pseudocode or code is the very same).

Comment: nvm, I saw the `curcount++;`  regardless this is still an iterative function in a recursive-function's clothing

Comment: ???? i am curious to see the "pure" recursive function in C. it's seem i do not have the same definition of recursive (not a problem !)

Comment: well, for 1, a 'pure' recursive function would actually be SIMPLER than the iterative version, and most importantly, it would use a recursive function call to calculate `previous`

Comment: Thanks divol! I used your code and tweaked it a little bit and it works fine. Now Sam, I want to see your SIMPLER code using 'pure' recursive function.

Comment: you're welcome Afungus :D my code was of course a draft even working .... When i made C and C++ courses i dreamed to have more curious students ....:D

Comment: @Afungus well, I suppose that I'm happy for you that you've had your assignment's requirements fulfilled for you, but I'm sad that you did not actually learn the essence of recursion in the process.  Now for the Simpler code that everyone's asking for, I had provided it from the very beginning.  It's that 2 line equation in my answer.  It's not in c, but the algorithm is there.  I'll make 1 last edit to draw your attention to the algorithm, but I will not do your homework for you.

Comment: very clever sam! my functional programing in too far away (caml ...) :D I need to practice some kata-programming for sure.

Comment: @Sam, I did your pseudo code in C and it worked. However it took a longer time for the computer to solve for the answers. I think divol's code is better because it's faster. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Afungus Yes, I'm sure that divol's code indeed was faster, and a lot of times iterative solutions are faster than recursion.  I suspect that the goal of this assignment was to get you to understand recursion, and what i provided is deeply more recursive than divol's answer.

Comment: @Afungus  Now, the reason why the more recursive answer went slower is probably due to the fact that there are 2 recursive calls in the function, resulting in a O(n^2) time complexity. Now, considering that both recursive calls are IDENTICAL, I'm sure that you can some up with a solution that does not have 2 recursive calls, and instead has O(n) time complexity.